# Cannot resolve method 'getStringArrayList' when I'm making a search filter for Listview

Tags: java, php, android, listview, arraylist

I'm a beginner, I'm creating a job search app which shows job infomation as listview where the data is from WAMP server database. I encounter a problem : Cannot resolve method 'getStringArrayList' , when I'm making a search filter for this Listview. Please see line 11 of SearchFilter.java. Could anyone help? thank you very much!

SearchFilter.java

```
public class SearchFilter extends ListActivity {
private EditText filterText = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            getStringArrayList()));                   ***<<<<< this line !***
}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://192.168.0.102/get_json_select_all.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_INFO = "info";
private static final String TAG_POSTNAME = "PostName";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "Location";
private static final String TAG_SALARY = "Salary";
private static final String TAG_RESPONSIBILITY = "Responsibility";
private static final String TAG_COMPANY = "Company";
private static final String TAG_CONTACT = "Contact";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray infos = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> infoList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    infoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    final ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostName))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Location))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Salary))
                    .getText().toString();

            HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<String, String>();
            info=(HashMap<String, String>)lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);


            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleContactActivity.class);

            in.putExtra(TAG_POSTNAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_LOCATION, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_SALARY, description);
            in.putExtra(TAG_RESPONSIBILITY,  info.get(TAG_RESPONSIBILITY));
            in.putExtra(TAG_COMPANY, info.get(TAG_COMPANY));
            in.putExtra(TAG_CONTACT, info.get(TAG_CONTACT));

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                infos = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_INFO);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < infos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = infos.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_POSTNAME);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_SALARY);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_RESPONSIBILITY);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_COMPANY);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    String mobile = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    info.put(TAG_POSTNAME, id);
                    info.put(TAG_LOCATION, name);
                    info.put(TAG_SALARY, email);
                    info.put(TAG_RESPONSIBILITY, address);
                    info.put(TAG_COMPANY, gender);
                    info.put(TAG_CONTACT, mobile);
                    // adding contact to contact list
                    infoList.add(info);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, infoList,

                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_POSTNAME, TAG_LOCATION,
                TAG_SALARY }, new int[] { R.id.PostName,
                R.id.Location, R.id.Salary });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <EditText android:id="@+id/search_box"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search Jobs"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"/>

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getStringArrayList` is a method on Bundle (such as savedInstanceState). There's no such method in Activity. Hope that helps.

Currently your infoList is an ArrayList>, something that is harder to pass directly to an activity. So find a way to represent it as an ArrayList, or find a more suitable datatype supported by Intent's putExtra-methods. Here below is a suggested solution using an ArrayList.

Passing the data into the activity with the Intent allows you to get it back in your SearchFilter. In the calling activity put something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SearchFilter.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("com.yourpackagename.here.keynamehere", aStringArrayList);
```

In SearchFilter.java, put something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    Intent startingIntent = getIntent();

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (startingIntent != null) {
       arrayList = startingIntent.getStringArrayList("com.yourpackagename.here.keynamehere");
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        arrayList));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wonder what can I do in order to make it works ?

Comment: telling what's the problem is good but not sufficient, you should put the solution too.

Comment: @niceman, the solution is to not call a method that doesn't exist. There is no expected behaviour explicitly stated, since this is basically a debugging-question.

 However, I will update my answer with some suggestions, since Calvin asked nicely.